# Bootstrap col size not working in form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5" placeholder="First Name">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
```

For large and medium, its working, but when I used it for mobile size, the input component always col-*-12, using form-inline its not working too, 
any idea?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to place these two inputs next to each other regardless of the viewport (so they will never stack) or something else?

Comment: Ya, I want to place these two each other, for large view no problem, but when I changed the viewport into xs or sm, the input field become col-*-12 so they are not next to each other

Comment: did you wrap that in a `<div class="row">`?

Comment: Also, if every size is `col-5` you don't need the larger sizes. All you need is `col-xs-5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use these codes

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5"><input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" placeholder="Last Name"></div>   
  </div>
</div>
```